# Expected Value of MLE parameter of Pareto distribution

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

The maximum likelihood estimator for a [Pareto Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) is given by:

$$\alpha = \frac{n}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^n ln x_i - ln x_{min}}$$

I want to find the expected value of $\alpha$ but don't know how. I tried to:

$$E[\alpha] = E[n(\sum_\limits{i=1}^n ln(\frac{x_i}{x_{min}})^{-1}] = nE[\frac{1}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^n ln(\frac{x_i}{x_{min}})}]$$

And then i got stuck. The only thing i can think of is to break somehow $\frac{1}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^n ln(\frac{x_i}{x_{min}})}$ for each $x_i$ and then solve:

$$\int_\limits{0}^{\infty} ln(\frac{x_i}{x_{min}})\frac{ax_{min}^a}{x_i^{a+1}} dx_i$$

Where the second factor of the integral is the pareto pdf for $x_i$. Can someone help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Parameter_estimation From the last line it state the result that the estimator $\hat{\alpha}$ has an inverse gamma distribution. You may try to verify that.

Comment: @BGM I've updated the question with some advances i've made. Any suggestions or corrections?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345895/distribution-of-sum-j-1n-ln-left-fracx-jx-1-right-when-x-1?noredirect=1&lq=1